# ListBox.SelectedIndex = -1 is not unsetting the selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selecteditem

I have a listbox defined in XAML is follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listLeagues" DisplayMemberPath="LeagueName" 
         SelectionChanged="listLeagues_SelectionChanged"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject, Mode=TwoWay}"
         SelectionMode="Single"    
         BorderBrush="{StaticResource noBrush}" Background="{StaticResource noBrush}"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
</ListBox>
```

In code I set the DataContext as follows:  `listLeagues.ItemsSource = Leagues;` where 'Leagues' is a custom collection. I am trying to change the selected Item in code with the following code:

```
    private void addButton_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FantasyLeague addedLeague = new FantasyLeague();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        addedLeague.LeagueName = "New Leauge " + rnd.Next(100).ToString();

        Leagues.Add(addedLeague);

        listLeagues.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listLeagues.SelectedItem = addedLeague;
        LeagueDetailsClickHelper();
    }
```

My listbox has SelectionMode = Single.  The line `listLeagues.SelectedIndex = -1;` has no affect and when changing the SelectedItem to a new value it has both items as SelectedItems even though the mode is single.  Can someone explain what is going wrong?

Thanks so much for your help.

EDIT

I have removed the `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject, Mode=TwoWay}"` from the XAML and found that things are working properly [most of the time].  I am updating the underlying source of the ListBox and when changing values that affect the == operator assessment to be different from the original values then I have noticed the SelectionChanged event doesn't include anything in the RemovedItems.  I am going to attempt to make a deep copy of the object and change the deep copy and see if that solves my issue.

FINAL UPDATE

I made a deep copy of the FantasyLeague that is in the Leagues collection.  I have members of the FantasyLeauge bound to a form which can be changed.  When I made the deep copy of this the source of the form that allowed changes to the Leagues collection instead of the original there were no problems.  I'm not sure why changing values that are linked to the assessment of == and .Equals would cause this behavior and not just update the target/source correctly, however, I have worked around the issue.  If anyone has input on what causes this behavior I would appreciate it.  Thanks for everyone that made suggestions.

Comment: Try setting the SelectedItem property to null first and the assign the newly added item as the selected item.

Comment: I added the line `listLeagues.SelectedItem = null;` but it has no affect either.

Comment: did you try changing the xaml to SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject, Mode=OneWay}"

Comment: I have attempted TwoWay, OneWay, and Default without success.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Okay well first thing is you should be using an `ObservableCollection` for binding.

Second, you are setting the actual UI `SelectedIndex` to -1 (which completely defeats the purpose of binding). You need to set the index of the `DataSource`.

Try that and possibly post the rest of your code.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "set the index of the datasource". As the datasource is the Leagues collection I don't understand what you are suggesting. The Leagues custom collection is not an Observable collection.  I am teaching myself to program and  chose this one to try and implement the INotifyCollectionChanged interface. I'm not sure how the Observable collection would be relevant as I'm not having issues updating the ListBox via the underlying collection but am having issues with the SelectedItem property. I'm just now sure what other code is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
listLeagues.SelectedIndex = -1;
    listLeagues.SelectedItem = addedLeague;
**listLeagues.UpdateLayOut();**
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old but since it shows high in my search I wanted to update the answer. I think you should use .ClearSelected() method, [MSDN info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.clearselected(v=vs.110).aspx) . That should clear out the any selections in a listbox C# or VBA (.net).

Cheers,